# XSL if testing for tag attributes

Tags: xslt, if-statement

This shouldn't be a hard one, but XSL documentation is not especially friendly as these things are concerned:

I'm trying to transform a document that has tags like such:

```
<Region>string</Region>
<Region class="unknown">string</Region>
```

I already handle the former case with

```
<xsl:for-each select="region">
<tags>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I need if-else syntax for the class="unknown" condition.

Mind providing a newbie example of how to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would tell us what you want to actually _do_ when the class attribute is present (and whether the value needs to be taken into account).  What is the expected output? You may not actually need if-else handling after all.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use **xsl:for-each** and **xsl:if** or **xsl:choose**, another approach to this would be to use template matching with **xsl:apply-templates** instead.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Region" />
```

Then you have (at least) two separate templates to match the **region** elements.

```
<xsl:template match="Region[@class='unknown']">
    <!-- Do something -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Region">
    <!-- Do something else -->
</xsl:template>
```

Do note that in this case the XSLT processor should always match the more specific template first (the one with the check for the @class attribute), and so the second template will only match the **region** elements without such an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward analog to if-else in XSLT is provided through choose-when-otherwise:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <!-- if -->
    <xsl:when test="@class= 'knownClass'">
       <!-- Do something -->
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- else if -->
    <xsl:when test="@class= 'unknown'">
       <!-- Do something else -->
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- else -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <!-- Default case -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

As with if-else statements, an `<xsl:choose>` can have 1 or more `<xsl:when>`s and the `<xsl:otherwise>` is optional.

In your case, you could put this right inside the `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="region">
   <xsl:choose>
       ...
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You will find it easier to read and understand the documentation if you learn the correct names for concepts. The things you are processing in your document are not tags, they are elements. Also, XML element names are case sensitive: "region" and "Region" are different names.